# Include TCDL tag in component presentation for a component

Tags: dynamic-linking, componentpresentation, tcdl, component

Let me give you a clear picture of my requirement.
I have a component having only one RTF field. Lets say I have 100 components using that particular component.Now whenever there is some changes made in RTF component it is not getting reflected in 100 components. 
So it is really tedious to publish 100 components again.
I was looking for dynamic component by including tcdl component presentation. Though I am able to process tcdl tags but not able to render RTF component dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific around "not able to"? Please share your template and Content Delivery code, describe the specific issue.

Comment: Please can you try to ask a question? It's not clear what you want to achieve. I'm guessing that you want to include a dynamically rendered component presentation in the output from a static component presentation. That's a bit unusual, but it should be possible. Is that what you want? What have you tried so far? You'll need to improve the question before anyone can answer it. If you don't, it will pretty soon get flagged for deletion, as it's already starting to look like you've abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your case correctly, the solution would be to publish the one component with the RTF field that was edited.

Tridion will then automatically publish all the 100 components that use it which in term may trigger publising of all the pages those 100 components may be included on. Or publishing of even more components if any of those 100 components are used by other components.

In short; to warrant content consistency  Tridion will, by design, publish all related content when publishing a component. Depending on your content model even publishing a single component can lead to a publish transaction of 100's of components and pages. For this reason it is recommended to publish the component after an edit is made rather than publishing the page its on.